# Unwanted page break and overflow after \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, overflow

When this code compiles it makes an empty page after the table of contents and the next page overflows, if anyone knows why or can help please do. I have no clue what i did wrong :(

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=3.14cm, bottom=3cm, outer=2.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}    
\fancyfoot{}

\fancyhead[l]{Vektorer i rummet}
\fancyhead[r]{Name Nameson}

\fancyfoot[l]{school}
\fancyfoot[r]{Side \thepage{}\hspace{1mm}af~\pageref{LastPage}}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indhold}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    {\Huge Vektorer i rummet}

    \vspace{0.25cm}

    {\large Name Nameson, Matematik A}
\end{center}

\tableofcontents

\section{Øvelsesopgaver i vektorer i rummet}

\subsection{Bestem koordinaterne til vektorerne $\vec{AB}$, $\vec{DC}$, $\vec{AC}$ og $\vec{CB}$}

\subsubsection*{Når $A(-1, 0, 4)$, $B(3, 7, -1)$, $C(6, -1, 0)$ og $D(1, 4, -5)$}

\subsection{Angiv koordinaterne til $B$}
\subsubsection*{Når $A(1, -2, -3)$ og $\vec{AB} = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\ -3 \\ 4
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsection{Afgør om punkterne udspænder et parrallelogram, og find bekræftende fald i koordinaterne til diagonalens skæringspunkt}

\subsubsection*{Når $A(2, -4, 1)$, $B(4, 2, 3)$, $C(3, 8, 2)$, $D(1, 2, 0)$}

\subsubsection*{Når $A(-1, 3, -4)$, $B(5, -1, 3)$, $C(-2, 3, -1)$, $D(4, -1, 6)$}

\subsubsection*{Når $A(4, -7, 2)$, $B(-3, 6, 1)$, $C(-1, 3, 0)$, $D(6, -10, 1)$}

\subsection{Beregn længderne af følgende vektorer}

\subsubsection*{Når $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    -9 \\ -12 \\ 8
\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    14 \\ -7 \\ 14
\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{c} = \begin{pmatrix}
    -9 \\ 18 \\ 18
\end{pmatrix}$ og $\vec{d} = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\ - \sqrt{3} \\ 3
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsection{Angiv skalarprodukterne $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$, $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}$ og $\vec{b} \cdot \vec{c}$}

\subsubsection*{Når $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    -3 \\ 7 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    6 \\ 1 \\ -3
\end{pmatrix}$ og $\vec{c} = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\ -5 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsubsection*{Når $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} \\ 6 \\ -4
\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    7 \\ 0 \\ -2
\end{pmatrix}$ og $\vec{c} = \begin{pmatrix}
    6 \\ -1 \\ 3
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsection{Løs følgende ligninger}

\subsubsection*{$\begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\ 4 \\ 5
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ -1 \\ a
\end{pmatrix} = -6$}

\subsubsection*{$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ a \\ 2a
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    a \\ -a \\ a
\end{pmatrix} = -6$}

\subsection{Vis, at der for følgende vektorer gælder, at $|\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}| = |\vec{a}| \cdot |\vec{b}|$}

\subsubsection*{$\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    -4 \\ 1 \\ 2
\end{pmatrix}$ og $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    8 \\ -2 \\ -4
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsubsection*{$\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    4 \\ 1 \\ -3
\end{pmatrix}$ og $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    -12 \\ -3 \\ 9
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsubsection*{Hvad gælder, i begge tilfælde, om forbindelsen mellem $\vec{a}$ og $\vec{b}$?}

\subsection{Bestem skalarprodukterne $\vec{AB} \cdot \vec{BC}$ og $\vec{AC} \cdot \vec{CB}$}

\subsubsection*{Når $A(3, -2, 7)$, $B(-4, -3, 1)$ og $C(1, 0, -6)$}

\subsection{Bestem tallet $t$, så $\vec{a}$ og $\vec{b}$ bliver ortogonale}

\subsubsection*{Når $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ t \\ t
\end{pmatrix}$ og $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    -3 \\ 2 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsubsection*{Undersøg, om der findes værdier af $t$, der gør $\vec{a}$ og $\vec{b}$ parallelle}

\subsubsection*{Bestem endelig $t$ og $k$, så $\vec{a}$ og $\vec{kb}$ bliver enhedsvektorer}

\subsection{Bestem vinklen mellem vektorerne $\vec{a}$ og $\vec{b}$}

\subsubsection*{Når $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 1 \\ 2
\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\ 5 \\ 8
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsubsection*{Når $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\ 3 \\ 5
\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    8 \\ 13 \\ 21
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsection{Bestem de reelle tal $k$, for hvilke $\vec{a}$ og $\vec{b}$ er parallelle, hhv. ortogonale}

\subsubsection*{Når $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    k - 1 \\ k \\ k + 1
\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    -k \\ 2k \\ -k
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsubsection*{Når $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    3k \\ k - 7 \\ 2k + 1
\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    10 - k \\ 2k - 9.5 \\ k - \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$}

\subsection{Bestem tallet $t$ således, at vinklen mellem $\vec{a}$ og $\vec{b}$ er 60\textdegree{}}

\subsubsection*{Når $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}$ og $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\ t \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$}

\end{document}
```

Here is what the rendered PDF looks like.

[image: First page (table of contents)]
[image: Second page (empty)]
[image: Third page (overflowing)]

Any help or explanation would be appreciated, i use the pdfLaTeX compiler, but i've tried compiling it using other compilers and the same still issue comes up :(

Comment: If you warp all your content into `\subsubsection{..}` latex has a very hard time to find possible spots to break your page.... What's the purpose of all your subsubsections?

Comment: your document just has section headings with no text and as a page break is not allowed after a section heading, there is nowhere to have a page break

Comment: Thank you, the problem seems to have solved itself when i added text to the sections :)